# Robocopy's copy criteria when MINAGE and MAXAGE is specified

Tags: robocopy, copying, files

What attribute does Robocopy look at when applying the MINAGE and MAXAGE flags? Date created or updated? If a group of files is created and later one of them is updated, if I run Robocopy with a later date range will the updated file be copied?

Comment: have you considered changing which answer is accepted, given the currently accepted answer is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to this Technet thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ITCG/thread/b5cb685e-32f6-4eed-855d-e710ca4b203f):

`minage` and `maxage` refer to the creation date of the file.

`minlad` and `maxlad` refer to the last write time of the file.

[Note that on later versions of Windows (I think vista and later), last access time stamping is off by default to improve performance](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2006/11/07/disabling-last-access-time-in-windows-vista-to-improve-ntfs-performance.aspx).

Comment: This answer is incorrect, and the Technet thread it links to is incorrect. `minage` and `maxage` refer to the Modified Date of the file, as also shown by the answer from @sparrowt

Answer (score 8):

There is confusion here and elsewhere, I believe the following is correct:

1. `minage` and `maxage` actually refer to the last **modified** date
   of the file (*not creation date*)
2. `minlad` and `maxlad` actually refer to the last **access** date of the file.

Sources for the above:

1. I tested `minage` with robocopy on Windows 7, and it used last modified date, not creation date. Also backed up by [this Technet thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c0d8c062-414d-4646-b1bc-dd289e1d9347/robocopy-delete-by-modified-or-create-date) and [this thread too](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/MS_DOS/Q_21010606.html).
2. [The robocopy documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) says that `minlad` & `maxlad` are the access date.

Comment: This is the correct answer. `minage` and `maxage` refer to the Modified Date of the file.